# Hadoop on Mac OS X - How to get pipes to work if i installed Hadoop using brew?

Tags: c++, macos, hadoop

I installed hadoop on OS X using `brew install hadoop`.

However, it seems i need to compile some source files in order to use pipes.
http://cxwangyi.blogspot.jp/2010/04/running-hadoop-on-mac-os-x-single-node.html
http://hadoop.illecker.at/?cat=4

How do I get the source files from brew installation?
Do I need to uninstall the brew version and re-install manually as explained here?
http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

Comment: Did you get hadop Pipes library work in your system? Then please share your solution with us. Thanks!